# What am I missing here? The program runs, but only the first if statement runs when i type in Sin in any case

Tags: java

What am I missing here? The program runs, but only the first if statement runs when i type in Sin in any case. When i type cos or tan. It will just print literally just cos, or tan.

```java
public class SinCosTanFormula {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    double angle, sin, cos, tan, opp, adj, hyp;
    boolean function;

    System.out.println("ENTER Function Needed (ex. sin, cos, tan)");
    System.out.print("> ");
    function = sc.hasNext();

    if (function == sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("sin")) {
      System.out.println("(Sin = opp/hyp )");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("ENTER Angle > ");
      angle = sc.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("ENTER Opposite Side of Angle >");
      opp = sc.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("ENTER Hypotenuse Side > ");
      hyp = sc.nextDouble();
      sin = opp / hyp;
      System.out.println("Sin" + "(" + angle + ")" + " = " + sin);

    } else if (function == sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("cos")) {
      System.out.println("(Cos = adj/hyp )");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("ENTER Angle > ");
      angle = sc.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("ENTER Adjacent Side of Angle > ");
      adj = sc.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("ENTER Hypotenuse Side > ");
      hyp = sc.nextDouble();
      cos = adj / hyp;
      System.out.println("Cos" + "(" + angle + ")" + " = " + cos);

    } else if (function == sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("tan")) {
      System.out.println("(Tan = opp/adj )");
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("ENTER Angle > ");
      angle = sc.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("ENTER Opposite Side of Angle > ");
      opp = sc.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("ENTER Adjacent Side of Angle > ");
      adj = sc.nextDouble();
      tan = opp / adj;
      System.out.println("Tan" + "(" + angle + ")" + " = " + tan);

    } else {
      System.out.println("Check inputted data");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you think `function == sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("cos")` means?

Comment: Your formatting style is magical :)

Comment: Thank you everybody,  thanks sasha, im flabbergasted lol

Answer (score 5):

You should only call `sc.next()` once, before all the if statements - store it somewhere and use that in the if-statements instead.

When you put `sc.next()` in each if check, and your input doesn't match 'sin', then it'll stop there and wait for input because the `else if` block that's coming up also has an `sc.next()` call.

Here's what your program is really doing:

```
if (the next input is "sin") {

} else (get another input and check if it's "cos") {

} else (get another input and check if it's "tan") {

} else {
    print error message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase(...
```

You are pulling another word / token every time you call sc.next(). This is why it is not working